# Gdebi-core package is not available

Tags: gdebi

```
sudo apt-get install -f gdebi-core
[sudo] password for sdksdk:
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Loading state information ... Done
Gdebi-core package is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean,
that the package is missing, it has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
```

Answer (score 5):

First check that `universe` is enabled. You can enable it by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

Then run the command:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Answer (score 2):

The package `gdebi-core` is in the [main repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?lang=en&suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gdebi-core). Check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` for an entry like this, eg. for trusty:

For the  distribution Trusty, eg:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

See your  distribution with the command

```
lsb_release -sc
```

from `man lsb_release`

```
-c, --codename
      Display the code name of the currently installed distribution.

-s, --short
      Use  the  short  output  format  for any information displayed.
      This format omits the leading header(s).
```

If the entry is missing, use this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main"
```

After that:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gedbi-core
```